# `administrator command: Prepare` is top offending query in Perona's pt-query-digest

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-slow-query-log, pt-query-digest

I am seeing the worst performing query as `administrator command: Prepare` over the last 12 hours where we saw a huge CPU usage spike in MySQL today. All of the usages of this query took 10+ seconds to execute.

We are using [Percona pt-query-digest analysis tool](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html).

There are plenty of other normal queries and details as expected in positions 2+. We've also run this tool against our slow query log numerous times without seeing `administrator command: Prepare`

I have looked all over for examples of a similar result but have found none. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any Stored Routines that include `PREPARE`?  Any that were changed recently?

Comment: @RickJames - no. We did discover that some table ALTER commands were run at the same time as the spike. We're thinking it had to do with that.